# how to read a value from properties file of an enum type?

Tags: java, enums, properties

I have an enum as below:

```
public enum EnvironmentType {PRODUCTION, TEST, DEVELOPMENT}
```

in properties file the key value is like :

```
app.environmentType = TEST
```

we know that when i read the value from properties file using key, it returns as String like

```
String envType = properties.getProperty("app.environmentType");
```

My requirement is,

```
EnvironmentType envType = EnvironmentType.TEST;
```

Now i want to know that is there a way to get the value as `enum` type? how can i `parse` or `cast` it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
EnvironmentType envType =   EnvironmentType.valueOf(envTypeString);
```

Comment: Note that this will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if `envTypeString` contains something that does not correspond to one of the enum constants - that's how you could check if the value is valid.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `valueOf` method as follows:

```
String envTypeStr = properties.getProperty("app.environmentType");
EnvironmentType envType = EnvironmentType.valueOf(envTypeStr);
```

The static methods `valueOf()` and `values()` are created at compile time and do not appear in source code. But they appear in documentation of some enumaration in java library. For example, see [`SortOrder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SortOrder.html) and [`Normalizer.Form`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.Form.html)